# SQL: result of left join left join left join left/right join

Tags: sql-server, left-join, right-join

When you have 3 o more tables, for example, table1 [1a,1b], table2[2a,2b] and table3 [3a,3b]

If I have:

```
SELECT table1.id , table2.id, table3.id 

FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.t1_id
LEFT/RIGHT JOIN table3 on table2.id = table3.t2_id
```

As result, first I'll have every table1.id

```
1a
1b
```

Then all the tuples where table2 matches table1, and the tuples from table1 that don't have a match in table2 are empty in table2.id.

```
1a   2a
1a   2b
1a
1b   2b
```

*Asumming those are the matches**

Here tell me if I'm getting this wrong or not

AND THEN, what do I have with a Left join and with a right join with the table3? :/

EDIT: I forgot, 3a will match with 2a and 2b and 3b with neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a `FULL OUTER` join in SQL Server and your result set would look like this

```
1a   2a  3a
1a   2b  3a
1a
1b   2b  
         3b
```

Edited to match your table 3 data.